# Generate 4-digit years format from as.date()

Tags: r

I want to generate list of URL which looping from startDate to the endDate. However the valid URL written in 4-digit years and the result come out in 2-digit format. Here I'm using Lubridate package. I believe there are simpler one for this. How can I improve this code ? Thank you..

```
startDate <- as.Date("01-11-17", format="%d-%m-%y")
endDate <- as.Date("31-01-18",format="%d-%m-%y")
theDay <- startDate

while (theDay <= endDate)
{ 
  dy <- as.character(theDay, format="%d")
  month <- as.character(theDay, format = "%m")
  year <- as.character(theDay, format ="%y")
  link <- "http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?"
  address <- 
   paste0(link,year,"&MONTH=",month,"&FROM=",dy,"00&T0=",dy,"00&STNM=48657")
  print(address)
  theDay = theDay + 1
}
```

Comment: Use `%Y`, `year <- as.character(theDay, format ="%Y")`

Comment: You can probably use the year function: year <- year(theDay) https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/year.html

Answer (score 2):

You should try `%Y`. See `?strptime`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without a loop as follows.  u is now a character vector of URLs.

```
link <- "http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?"
params <- "region=naconf&TYPE=TEXT:LIST&YEAR=%Y&MONTH=%m&FROM=%d00&T0=%d00&STNM=48657"
fmt <- paste0(link, params)

u <- format(seq(startDate, endDate, by = "day"), format = fmt)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the function year() from the package lubridate. Below is the code:

```
startDate <- as.Date("01-11-17", format="%d-%m-%y")
year(startDate)

#[1] 2017
```

Comment: There are also the functions month() and day(), if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `lubridate`, just use the `year` function:
`year <- year(theDay)`

```
library(lubridate)
startDate <- as.Date("01-11-17", format="%d-%m-%y")
endDate <- as.Date("31-01-18",format="%d-%m-%y")
theDay <- startDate

while (theDay <= endDate)
{ 
  address <- 
    paste0("http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?",
           year(theDay),
           "&MONTH=",sprintf("%02d", month(theDay)) ,
           "&FROM=",sprintf("%02d", day(theDay)) ,"00&T0=",sprintf("%02d", day(theDay)) ,
           "00&STNM=48657")
  print(address)
  theDay = theDay + 1
}
```